# What is JS Callback Best Pracitce if B and C are depending on A?

Tags: javascript

I think I have my head wrapped around the Javascript callback functions when it comes to one on one, i.e.

```
   funcA  // generates some params needed for funcB
   funcB
```

Can be implemented as

```
   function funcA (Aparams callback) {
      //some processing using Aparams to generate params
      callback(params)
   }

   function funcB (Bparams) {
      //waiting for Bparams
      //some processing
   }

   //main program
   funcA(something,funcB)
```

But what is the best way to implement...

```
   funcA  // generates some params needed for funcB AND funcC?
   funcB
   funcC
```

Assume same params can be used for both B and C.

I thought about chaining them, but I kinda got lost in the syntax. I don't want to run funcA twice, once with B and once with C, which would be the brute force method.

Comment: Are you talking about asynchronous callbacks that will be called exactly once? If so, the best practice is to use promises instead.

Comment: Apparently I wasn't being absolutely clear. Yes, assume there's an AJAX call in funcA, so funcB must WAIT until funcA completes and generated params for it.

Comment: @Bergi My JS class hasn't reached "promise" chapter yet. I'll have to look into it myself.

Comment: I just wanted to ensure that it's the ajax use case. There are other usages of callbacks where the answers would be different, e.g. the callbacks to array `forEach`, array `map` or dom element `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for

```
funcA(something, function(aResults) {
    funcB(aResults);
    funcC(aResults);
});
```

Comment: Interesting. Never thought about doing an anon function that calls both of them as callbacks. But can you pass an anon function WITH a parameter like that as the callback? I thought callback functions in the declaration has no parameters, being a pointer to the actual function.

Comment: So what you're really telling me is I am better off writing a funcD and use that as the callback function, and within funcD, run funcB and funcC?

Comment: Whether it is anonymous, or defined elsewhere and referenced from the call does not make any difference. Yes, callback functions ought to have parameters, otherwise they could not receive the arguments passed to them in the `callback(params)` call. The declaration of the name `callback` in the parameters of `funcA` does not matter for that at all.

Comment: Yes, another function that calls both of them is exactly the solution you are currently looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need a callback to achieve it. you can use.

```
let A_res = funcA(param);
funcB(A_res);
funcC(A_res);
// This is suitable in All when there is no async Process in funcA...
```

Now definitely in case of async process in funcA you need a call back...

```
function funcA(param){
   // processing...
   let Temp_A_res = processed_result;
   return function (callBack){
    callBack(Temp_A_res);
   }
}
let A_res = funcA();// A_res will be a function which take further call back...
A_res(funcB);
A_res(funcC);
```

This all that I have shown is easily done by promises Please Read them too..

Comment: But it appears that your solution runs A twice, once for B, and once for C. I think I specified that I don't want to run it twice.

Comment: It wont run twice, the funcA is only called once and return another function which always keep the result of A as it closures. then running A_res() will run only the inner function not he processing